# go to beginning of text in a line (not beginning of line) in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, <kbd>C-a</kbd> runs the command `org-beginning-of-line`, which takes me to the beginning of a heading.

`▐ *** heading 3`

Is there a keystroke that will take me to the beginning of the content, since what I want to edit is not the stars but the text?

`*** ▐ heading 3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See variable org-special-ctrl-a/e